# Fourier Synthesis of randomly generated Sinusoidal waves using Math.NET Numerics

Tags: c#, .net, random, generator, fft

I'm trying to create a generator (i.e. a `IEnumerable<double>`) that mimics the variability of a power grid frequency signal.  I had the idea that if I overlay some noise over the top of a series of composed sine waves, I might be able to get the kind of plausible shape I need.

Here's a good example of the kind of curve I need to reproduce. Not necessarily with the frequency excursion, which I can handle separately.

[image]

Alas, my math is a bit shaky on this and I can't find any nice libraries to handle the composition itself.  Does anyone know how to piece together a new distribution given a set of generators based on `Generate.Sinusoidal` (see here: [Math.NET Numerics Generation](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Generate))

Comment: BTW: Math.NET Numerics is not mandatory for the solution, it's just something I'm already using, I'm just interested in end results.

Comment: I am not familiar with the term 'Fourier Synthesis'. Do you mean additive synthesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_synthesis)? I.e. you add a few sinusoids of different frequencies, phase, and amplitudes to obtain a desired waveform? (Obviously, this is related to the Fourier transform/Fourier series in general.)

Comment: What are _"Randomly Generated Sinusoidal Waves"_? Are they a set of sine waves of random frequency, phase and amplitude? Something else?

Comment: If my description is correct, and you have a way of creating a sine wave of a give frequency, amplitude and phase as a time series, then the solution is pretty obvious. Get a set of _wave generators_ as IEnumerables, configure them as you want (_randomly_), create a _composer_ (which, I'm assuming will add or average them) and the output the composed signal

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, exactly, not only not smooth but designed to not line up.

Comment: @dmedine yes, I suppose..  Maybe that phrase is just a UK term?
https://www.encyclopedia.com/science/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/fourier-synthesis

Comment: @Flydog57 then draw the rest of the owl? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with the following, which generates curves that reasonably closely resemble the creeping movement of a grid frequency curve.

```cs
    public static double frequency  => GridFrequency(500, 0.1).First();


    public static IEnumerable<double> GridFrequency(int basePeriod, double amplitudeLimits)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            // Assuming you have your time series data in an array
            double[] timeSeriesData = Generate.Normal(1000, 50, 0.01);// new double[1000]; // Replace 1000 with the appropriate size

            // Assuming you have 10 amplitude and frequency values in arrays

            double[] amplitudes = new double[3]; // Fill this array with your amplitude values
            double[] frequencies = new double[3]; // Fill this array with your frequency values
            double[] phases = new double[3];// new double[3]{1.0/500.0, 1/100.0, 0.2 }; // Fill this array with your frequency values

            for (int i = 0; i < amplitudes.Length; i++)
            {
                amplitudes[i] = 10 * amplitudeLimits * (amplitudeLimits / (1 + Math.Sinh(i)));// (1.0 / (i + 1)) * random.NextDouble();
                frequencies[i] = 1.0 / (basePeriod * (i + 1) * random.NextDouble());
                phases[i] = 2 * i * Math.PI * random.NextDouble();
            }

            // Add sinusoidal noise to the time series data
            AddSinusoidalCurves(timeSeriesData, amplitudes, frequencies, phases);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                yield return timeSeriesData[i];
            }
        }

    }

    static void AddSinusoidalCurves(double[] data, double[] amplitudes, double[] frequencies, double[] phases)
    {
        // Check if the number of amplitude and frequency values matches
        if (amplitudes.Length != frequencies.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The number of amplitude values must be equal to the number of frequency values.");
        }

        int n = data.Length;

        // Add sinusoidal noise to the data
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            double noise = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < amplitudes.Length; j++)
            {
                double amplitude = amplitudes[j];
                double frequency = frequencies[j];
                double phase = phases[j];
                noise += amplitude * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency * i + phase);
            }

            // Add the noise to the data point at index i
            data[i] += noise;
        }
    }
```

And here is a sample of the output.

[image]